# How to join two Spark DataFrame and operate their share column?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have 2 DataFrame like this:

```
+--+-----------+
|id|some_string|
+--+-----------+
| a|        foo|
| b|        bar|
| c|        egg|
| d|        fog|
+--+-----------+
```

and this:

```
+--+-----------+
|id|some_string|
+--+-----------+
| a|        hoi|
| b|        hei|
| c|        hai|
| e|        hui|
+--+-----------+
```

I want to join them to be like this:

```
+--+-----------+
|id|some_string|
+--+-----------+
| a|     foohoi|
| b|     barhei|
| c|     egghai|
| d|        fog|
| e|        hui|
+--+-----------+
```

so, the column `some_string` from the first dataframe is concantenated to the column `some_string` from the second dataframe. If I am using

```py
df_join = df1.join(df2,on='id',how='outer')
```

it would return

```
+--+-----------+-----------+
|id|some_string|some_string|
+--+-----------+-----------+
| a|        foo|        hoi|
| b|        bar|        hei|
| c|        egg|        hai|
| d|        fog|       null|
| e|       null|        hui|
+--+-----------+-----------+
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`when`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) in order to achieve proper concatenation. Other than that the way you were using `outer` join was almost correct.

You need to check if anyone of these two columns is [`Null`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isNull) or [`not Null`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isNotNull) and then do the [`concatenation`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat).

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, concat
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('a','foo'),('b','bar'),('c','egg'),('d','fog')],['id','some_string'])
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('a','hoi'),('b','hei'),('c','hai'),('e','hui')],['id','some_string'])
df_outer_join=df1.join(df2.withColumnRenamed('some_string','some_string_x'), ['id'], how='outer')
df_outer_join.show()
+---+-----------+-------------+
| id|some_string|some_string_x|
+---+-----------+-------------+
|  e|       null|          hui|
|  d|        fog|         null|
|  c|        egg|          hai|
|  b|        bar|          hei|
|  a|        foo|          hoi|
+---+-----------+-------------+
df_outer_join = df_outer_join.withColumn('some_string_concat',
                                         when(col('some_string').isNotNull() & col('some_string_x').isNotNull(),concat(col('some_string'),col('some_string_x')))
                                         .when(col('some_string').isNull() & col('some_string_x').isNotNull(),col('some_string_x'))
                                         .when(col('some_string').isNotNull() & col('some_string_x').isNull(),col('some_string')))\
                              .drop('some_string','some_string_x')


df_outer_join.show()
+---+------------------+
| id|some_string_concat|
+---+------------------+
|  e|               hui|
|  d|               fog|
|  c|            egghai|
|  b|            barhei|
|  a|            foohoi|
+---+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to perform an outer join you can try the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, col, lit, when


df_join= df1.join(df2,on='id',how='outer').when(isnull(df1.some_string1), ''). when(isnull(df2.some_string2),'').withColumn('new_column',concat(col('some_string1'),lit(''),col('some_string2'))).select('id','new_column')
```

(Please note that the some_string1 and 2 refer to the some_string columns from the df1 and df2 dataframes. I would advise you to name them differently instead of giving the same name some_string, so that you can call them)

Comment: the values for null are not as per the requirement u need to use when clause here